# CartoDB - How do you do a line fill of polygons in CartoDB?

Tags: polygon, carto, carto-js

I would like to show overlaping layers with hash marks, is this possible by editing the css in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out, you need to refer to an image file, here I have referred to a png I uploaded to cartodb:

```
cartocss: "#layer_name[field='field_value'] {polygon-pattern-file: url(website/image.png); line-color: #9e1e62; line-width:1;}
```

- replace the png with the appropriate image
- replace layer_name with the appropriate layer
- replace field with the field you are querying on
- replace field_value with the value of the field you are querying on/would like to symbolize